# Alternative to window.location.href using POST request - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am writing below code in Javascript to retrieve comment and navigating same page after repopulating the data

```
function MoveItem() {

var empId = document.getElementById('EMP_ID').value;
var commentValue = $("#RESPONSE").val();
if ($.trim(commentToSave).length > 0) {
    showAjaxLoading();
    var empData= "APPROVE";
    var baseControllerUrl = '/Employee/EmpManagement/PushItem';
    window.location.href = baseControllerUrl + "/" + empId + "?comment=" + commentValue + "&empData=" + empData + "&currentItem=" + itemData;

} else {
    aet('Pelase enter comments', 'E');
  }
}
```

In controller the method written as

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> MoveItem(int id, string comment, string decision, string currentworkflow)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("EditEmpManagemnt", "EmpManagement", new { id = id });
   }
```

I want to convert MoveItem action method to a [HttpPost] type and what all changes are needed in Javascript & action method ? Can anyone explain with a sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a `POST` request using the `fetch` method. We send the data with the JSON format. Replace your javascript with this:

```
function MoveItem() {
    var empId = document.getElementById('EMP_ID').value;
    var commentValue = $("#RESPONSE").val();
    if ($.trim(commentToSave).length > 0) {
        showAjaxLoading();
        var empData = "APPROVE";
        var baseControllerUrl = '/Employee/EmpManagement/PushItem';

        var url = baseControllerUrl + "/" + empId;

        //here we put the url as a first parameter
        //then we configure the http method
        //and in the body we pass in the object in JSON format
        fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "comment": commentValue,
                "empData": empData,
                "currentItem": itemData
            })
        }).then(result => {
            //do something with the result you get back
            console.log("Completed with result: " + result);
        }).catch(err => {
            //if any error occured, then show it here
            console.log("There is an error: " + err);
        });
        
    } else {
        aet('Please enter comments', 'E');
    }
}
```

And in your C# code just replace `[HttpGet]` attribute with `[HttpPost]`

Comment: @Costa..have you seen that in controler method it using RedirectoAction...whether it will work properly using above code ?because it is repopulating data